# Angular template variable undefined on other tag

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this template on my angular v6.1 application:

[image]

But de video on the p tag comes undefined, but in the loadeddata function have the correct value.
I have a ngFor loop to read images and videos, for the videos I need the duration, width and heigh for each one of them.

I can't see where I'm doing wrong.

[stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/variable-template)

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz instance of your issue ?

Comment: Can u tell, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Prince I tried, but my company api isn't public and the stackblitz doesn't allowed to me to upload a video on the application.

Comment: @ngShravil.py I have a ngFor loop to read images and videos, for the videos I need the duration, width and heigh for each one of them.
I declared the template variable to get that information, but the video variable declared is undefined inside the paragraph tag.

Comment: Can you please attach full HTML pic where you have used ngFor loop ?

Comment: Hi @Prince I attached the stackblitz example. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we have asynchronous code here. Tag `p` get its data synchronously, but at the very beginning it is `undefined`. Then, when media has finished loading, video gets the data. That's why

> the loadeddata function have the correct value

[Here is the solution.](http://stackblitz.com/edit/variable-template-wc8hpg) The only drawback is that url of your video google chrome marks as suspicious, that's why metadata of the video can't be preloaded before you open the video in new tab.

Comment: Ok, I see.
Some way I can fix this and read the value on the `<p>`?

Comment: How are you getting the `video` variable? Through some service call?

Comment: The best way to fix it I know is to use Observables. Create Observable and subscribe for data it emits. After data is retrieved from Observable, your template will update. Look here, there are both Observable and AsyncPipe: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe
(the second example)

Comment: @ngShravil.py `video` is a template variable

Comment: @MaxKurtz I tried to use as in the example, but unfortunately without success, continues undefined.I think I'm to do an unconventional solution in my code.

Comment: @GabrielaMendes can you create minimal reproducible example on stackblitz.com (or on other sandbox)?

Comment: Just console the value of `video` in `getVideoInfo()` and post it.

Comment: @ngShravil.py I want to use the video template variable, not the method inside de typescript file. I removed method from the version on the stackblitz code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/variable-template

Comment: Here is the solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/variable-template-wc8hpg
The only drawback is that url of your video google chrome marks as suspicious, that's why metadata of the video can't be preloaded before you open the video in new tab.

Comment: @MaxKurtz sorry for the video url, the real one is from a bank api so unfortunately I can't to use on my example. The solution worked, I saw a made a mistake in the `p`context. :)

Comment: It's not a good practice to declare a template variables and use in the HTML. it's better to pass this value to a function and bind it to a typescript variable and display this variable in HTML with the help of `{{}}`.

Comment: @GabrielaMendes - great! I'm glad I've helped. But I agree with ngShravil.py, logic has to be handled in component.ts, and template cares about the markup. Good luck!